# C# IndexOutOfRangeException when calling Array.GetLength(1) for a 2D Array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

here is the code, 
I noticed that the Getlength method returns 0 but I think its normal as the for loop wont go further than 0..
I've written

```
int yy = tile.GetLength(1);
```

and it throws the same exception as the code under :

```
 TileData[][] tile = GameMain.Level.getCollisionTiles();

        Rectangle tileRectangle;
        for(int x = 0; x <= tile.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= tile.GetLength(1); y++) //EXCEPTION THROWN HERE AT GETLENGTH !!!!
            {
                tileRectangle = tile[x][y].Target;
                if (tileRectangle.Contains(m_hitbox)) //Si il y a collision
                {
                    if ((m_hitbox.X + m_hitbox.Width) > tileRectangle.X) //si le joueur percute par la gauche
                    {
                        m_hitbox.X--;
                    }
                    else if (m_hitbox.X < (tileRectangle.X + tileRectangle.Width)) //Droite
                    {
                        m_hitbox.X++;
                    }
                    if ((m_hitbox.Y + m_hitbox.Height) > tileRectangle.Y) //si le joueur percute par le haut
                    {
                        m_hitbox.Y--;
                    }
                    else if (m_hitbox.Y < (tileRectangle.Y + tileRectangle.Height)) //Bas
                    {
                        m_hitbox.Y++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT: I got it working by getting the tile info from the map object, but now it throws NullReferenceException

```
        TileData[][] tile = GameMain.Level.getCollisionTiles();
        int xMax = GameMain.Level.getMapHeight();
        int yMax = GameMain.Level.getMapWidth();

        for (int x = 0; x <= xMax; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= yMax; y++)
            {
                Rectangle tileRectangle = tile[x][y].Target; //THIS LINE FAILS !!!!
                if (tileRectangle.Contains(m_hitbox)) //Si il y a collision
                {
                    if ((m_hitbox.X + m_hitbox.Width) > tileRectangle.X) //si le joueur percute par la gauche
                    {
                        m_hitbox.X--;
                    }
                    else if (m_hitbox.X < (tileRectangle.X + tileRectangle.Width)) //Droite
                    {
                        m_hitbox.X++;
                    }
                    if ((m_hitbox.Y + m_hitbox.Height) > tileRectangle.Y) //si le joueur percute par le haut
                    {
                        m_hitbox.Y--;
                    }
                    else if (m_hitbox.Y < (tileRectangle.Y + tileRectangle.Height)) //Bas
                    {
                        m_hitbox.Y++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Sorry to ask you this question in the same topic, but i think you can help me resolving it fast.

Comment: It's not a 2D array. TileData[][] is **not** TileData[,]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a 2D array. `TileData[][]` is a jagged array, `TileData[,]` is a 2D array then, in your case, `GetLength(1)` will always fail because tile has only one dimension.

**EDIT**
What to do to solve this? You can change tile from [][] to [,] (for example) and keep everything else as is (how `getCollisionTiles()` works?) or you may update your code to get right size from jagged array, like this:

```
for (int y = 0; y < tile[x].GetLength(0); y++)
```

BTW you may even replace `GetLength(0)` with a simple `Length`:

```
for(int x = 0; x < tile.Length; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < tile[x].Length; y++)
```

Final note: for 0 based arrays Length is not inclusive for index so `x <= tile.Length` must be replaced with `x < tile.Length`.

Comment: thanks for answering, but then how am i supposed to get the length of the second [] in array ?

Comment: @user3005141 initilize your array that way:
TileData[,] tile = GameMain.Level.getCollisionTiles();

Comment: @user3005141 it depends what getCollisionTiles() returns...you may change your array to [,] instead of [][] or you can use a for to initialize each element (see updated answer).

Comment: The getCollisionTiles() returns a [][] array, but i havent written it, it depends of a framework, and when i try to convert it of course it says : Erreur 3 Unable to convert type 'FuncWorks.XNA.XTiled.TileData[][]' to 'FuncWorks.XNA.XTiled.TileData[*,*]'

Comment: @user3005141 There isn't one array for your second dimension.  There are N different arrays for the inner dimension, all potentially with a different length.  If you happen to know that they're all the same you can just pick one, but if they aren't all the same then you need to deal with that when accessing items.

Comment: Maybe i could be able to do the trick with a foreach loop, or i should try to cast the [][] array into a [,] one...     I didnt understood your answer Servy sorry :/ How should I be able to access the second [] ?

Comment: `[][]` is an array of arrays, not a two-dimensional array. You have to check the length of each array individually (`tile[0].Length, tile[1].Length, ...`).

Comment: Wow... I havent thought of that ! then how a X,Y coordinate can be stored in that array.. ?

Comment: @stalker2106 what do you mean with "how a X,Y coordinate can be **stored** in that array"?